# Cloning a git repo in GitLab - specific requirements

Tags: gitlab

I have a git repo that I have worked on for some time. It is cloned on my pc and has a few branches. I want to recreate this repo on GitLab along with all history and branches. I have seen that if the repo is accessible using a url it is easy to clone. But unfortunately mine is not. Any ideas how this can be accomplished. I have tried to upload the local repo folder to Azure storage account to make is publicly accessble but couldnt get the import working.
Thanks

Comment: Push it to gitlab.

Comment: Just to be clear, 

what you want to do is to push a local repository to a gitlab remote? Because if that's the case, the steps to make that happen are described in detail when you make a blank project on gitlab.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the local repository, with local branches (meaning not remote tracking branches in an `origin/<branches>` list), you can use [`git push --mirror`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---mirror) to push it to a new GitLab project.

```sh
cd /path/to/local/repo
git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/<me>/<newRepo>
git push --mirror
```